# Math.pow(x,2) area of square

Tags: java

i am running a code, but i dont seem to be able to get the scanner working, anyone got an idea how?

```
public class verk34 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 System.out.println(Math.pow(x,2));
 }
}
```

the thing is inserting a number on your own without altering the code.

Comment: This is not javascript

Comment: Have you assigned x with a value

Comment: this is dr java, is that not javascript?

Comment: and no, i have not assigned the x since that is what i am going to be using it for the input.

Answer (score 5):

As per my understanding, you need to add *Scanner* for taking input from end users and importing the *java.util.Scanner* statement.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: This is correct; however `Scanner` is in `java.util`.

Comment: do i also need a import java.something aswell?

Comment: @RagnarBerg: yes, you need to import java.util.Scanner

Comment: @hexafraction : Thanks for the help! I have updated the answer.

Comment: where in the code should i put it? just so i dont place it at the wrong spot?

Comment: you should also be aware that if you input a non number it will throw you an exception.  You might want to catch that.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your contribution. @OP: You could consider printing some sort of prompt to the user so they know that they meed to input a number). Additionally, using `double` and `nextDouble()` may be more appropriate depending on what input you expect.

Comment: The import should be placed at the top of all the code you write. All imports should be mentioned before the class declaration.

Comment: this has answered my question, thank you, it really helped.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import scanner and Math

```
import java.util.Scanner
import java.lang.Math
```

Then If I am understanding correctly the problem, you need to do this in two steps :

-**Instantiate a scanner** and collect user input as an integer.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" Please enter the square area :");

int userValue = sc.nextInt();
```

The nextInt method will **lock process** and wait for a keyboard event before continuing. So enter a nulber with your keyboard.

-**Use System.out.println with given value.**

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(userValue,2));
```